# How do I solve a "native bindings" issue?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with the sqlite3 node package in my VS Code extension.
It works on my system™ but does not work on a user's computer. Same version of SQLite 3.

On some systems, it works. On some others, it fails with error "Please install sqlite3 package manually" (see screenshot below for details)

When I asked ChatGPT, it said something about native bindings.

I figure if I will be able to fix this error myself, I need to understand how native bindings work.

Am I overlooking an obvious mistake here or what knowledge gap do i need to fill? Please help.

PS: for more information about the issue, check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/damms005/devdb-vscode/issues/35

[image]

Comment: don't make us click into an issue ticket to get info about the problem. see [ask]

Comment: I think the question actually contained enough info about the problem. I only added the issue ticket for more context. I will re-edit to make it clearer. Thank you